# How to add elements to vector without invoking copy-constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, copy-constructor, move-semantics

For some reason my temporary local object is always copy-constructed/destroyed when added to a vector which is causing problems due to nested `std::reference_wrapper` which are getting invalid because of the copy-construction and destruction afterwards (`std::reference_wrapper` targets are inside the object which gets destroyed -> so they are invalid in the copy-constructed object, if the source object is destroyed). But if possible I want to avoid the additional copying / destroying completely - that seems impossible, because whatever I tried always it wants to invoke the copy constructor (even using `std::vector::emplace_back`).

Considering this simple example (for easier understanding without `std::reference_wrapper` involved), it always tries to invoke the copy-constructor - I don't get why.

```
#include <vector>

class A{
public:
  A(int a) : a(a){ }
  int getInt() const{ return a; }
  A(const A&) = delete; /* to deny copy-construction */
private:
  int a;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  std::vector<A> vec;
  vec.emplace_back(3);              /* tries to call copy constructor */
  vec.push_back(A(3));              /* tries to call copy constructor */
  vec.push_back(std::move(A(3)));   /* tries to call copy constructor */
  return 0;
}
```

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: a) First two tries: Why shouldn´t it? b) About the std::move part, you´re missing a move constructor (ie. r-value reference parameter).

Comment: What compiler are you using? If the move constructor is not auto generated then you can never hope for the move constructor to be invoked. Also, for c++11 you should consider using `A(const A&) = delete` if you want to disable copying.

Comment: I'm using MS Visual Studio 2013. Thanks for the advice with `A(const A&) = delete`.

Comment: Reading [this `emplace_back` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back), the stored type have to be [move insertable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveInsertable) which states that placement new may be used like `::new((void*)p) T(rv)`, which will invoke the move-constructor *or* the copy-constructor if there's no move constructor.

Comment: @deviantfan To the best of my understanding, there are two potential copy-points here: the first emplacement, and internal buffer doubling. It's only the elimination of the second that requires a move ctor, no? the first could/should be done with placement new.

Comment: @deviantfan: a) I thought the whole point of `emplace_back` is, that no additional copy operation takes place & for the second try I was thinking RVO would apply there.

Comment: Well ... VS2013 doesn´t even fully support rvalue refs itself, so good luck if you want every detail of the API and auto-generation to be working correctly

Comment: Sounds like that your class contains a self-reference. For this kind of cases you have to write your own copy/move constructors to get proper semantics. Most `vector` operations requires the objects to be at least movable. Just disabling copy/move entirely isn't going to help you much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the Visual Studio 2013 [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#defaultedanddeleted), emphasis mine:

> "Rvalue references v3.0" adds new rules to **automatically generate move constructors and move assignment operators** under certain conditions. However, **this is not implemented in Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2013**, due to time and resource constraints.

Visual Studio 2013 is specified as using Rvalue references v2.1.

**Note:** As [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) notes in the comments there is also an issue with explicitly disabling the copy constructor in your example. Per [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor).

> If no user-defined move constructors are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), and all of the following is true:
>
> - there are no user-declared copy constructors
> - there are no user-declared copy assignment operators
> - there are no user-declared move assignment operators
> - there are no user-declared destructors
> - (until C++14) the implicitly-declared move constructor is not defined as deleted due to conditions detailed in the next section
>
> then the compiler will declare a move constructor as an inline public member of its class with the signature T::T(T&&).
>
> A class can have multiple move constructors, e.g. both T::T(const T&&) and T::T(T&&). If some user-defined move constructors are present, the user may still force the generation of the implicitly declared move constructor with the keyword default.

Which means your example code also prevents auto generation of the move constructor (i.e., it *has a user-declared copy constructor*).

You need to explicitly declare your move constructor and/or move assignment operator. The following works for your example.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int a) : a(a) {}

    A(const A&) = delete;

    A(A&& other) : a(other.a) {}

    int getInt() const { return a; }

private:
    int a;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<A> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(3);
    vec.push_back(A(3));
    vec.push_back(std::move(A(3)));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: VS2013's peculiarities are irrelevant in this case. The class has a user-declared copy constructor, so it won't be getting an implicitly declared move constructor even in a conforming compiler.

Comment: @T.C. You're correct that explicitly declaring copy operations disables auto generation of move operations. I just assumed the contrived example was only explicitly disabling the copy constructor to verify the code still worked (i.e., was relying upon the move operations).

Comment: @T.C. suppose this were a list instead of a vector (and so wouldn't do the internal buffer doubling thingy), would your point still stand? Why wouldn't it use placement new?

Comment: @JamesAdkison Your assumption is correct - I just explicitly disabled the copy constructor for verification